# Uploading file to Subfolder produces error "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I get the above error when trying to upload a file to a sharepoint subfolder in a library. I'm pretty sure the url is correct as it will give a "File not found error" if I change it too anything else.

```
    public void UploadFile(string client, IEnumerable<FileUpload> documents)
    {
        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            using (var context = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                var listCollection = context.Web.Lists;

                var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(client); //clientname

                context.ExecuteQuery();

                var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation()
                {
                    Content = document.FileBytes,
                    Url = @"https://sharepointsite.com/sites/client/docStore/clientname/cdae2d570ab24b02811a8bce88ebea64/new1.zip",
                    Overwrite = true
                };

                var file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);

                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've stripped out a few things from the code above to make it easier to read (folder createion/netwrok credentials). Can anyone see where I am going wrong here? Also is there a better way to do this? All the solutions I have seen to uploading to a subfolder is to supply the file URL. Is there a way I can explicitly upload to a folder in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL was wrong.

Should be /sites/client/docStore/clientname/cdae2d570ab24b02811a8bce88ebea64/new1.zip